# Can we give hardcoded path for sqlite in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to the iPhone development and Mac OS, please bear with the silly query. But I tried hard to  get into depth but couldn't found the solution for the problem.

I have created a database in sqlite through command prompt. The database is saved in Users/DNamto/resources.db

But when am trying to open this db in my iPhone application using the following code snippet

```
// Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resources.db"]];
```

The database fails to open up. 
The database path which the application is searching for is :
/Users/DNamto/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/C82C3DAF-4E95-49A7-9A4F-4D69B056DC9D/Documents/resources.db

Can anyone help me to get the correct database path.
Can we hard code the DB path so that my application links to it. If yes then please provide the code snippet.

Comment: you have to first make a copy of database in document folder and then you can open it

Comment: Thanks Girish nad Midhun MP for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your database in the application & check if the db is present in doc directory or not, if not then you need to copy it in doc directory and then access it. 
For cppy the db in doc directory use following code snippet

```
- (void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self getDBPath]];
    NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];
    if(success)
    {
        return;// remove old one.
    }
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:[self getDBPath] error:nil];
}
```

To open the db use following code snippet

```
-(void)openDatabase
{
    @try
    {
        [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
        if(sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath] UTF8String], &mainDatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Database opened");
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception in openDatabase %@ :%@",exception.name,exception.reason);
    }
}

- (NSString *)getDBPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];
}
```

Use following code snippet to close the database.

```
-(void)closeDatabase:(sqlite3_stmt*)statement
{
    @try
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(mainDatabase);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception in DatabaseController closeDatabase %@ :%@",exception.name,exception.reason);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't prefix methods w/`get`.  That should just be `dbPath` or `databasePath`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't. In real device you can't get the hard coded path.**

**You need a relative path.**

Here your issue is your database is not present in the document directory.

You need to add your database to your main bundle and in run time you need to check whether the db is present on document directory, if not you need to copy it to document directory using the `NSFileManager.`

You can use the following code to copy the database file from bundle to document directory.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resource.db"];
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resource.db"];
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:folderPath error:&error];
```